# How to copy and paste the content in selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can any one please guide me how I can copy content from one site and migrate to other side with the help of selenium WebDriver ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you want to perform an copy/paste of the website directory to another folder ?

Or do you want to parse the html contents, and save that in an external file ?

The former is not really selenium friendly.

Comment: I just want to post data from one website to other website form and submit the same.

Answer (score 0):

So an simple example of what you want is this :

Website 1:

```
    <span id="spanID"> content in here </span>
```

Website 2:

```
    <form id="inputID"> [ you want content in here ] </form>
```

**Please note the pseudo html.**

What you need to do in order to make this work is..

```
  browser.get("http://www.website1.com);

  var tempElement = $("spanID"); 
  tempElement .getText().then(function (contentOfSpan) {
               console.log(contentOfSpan); // will print the content of the span... now you want to save this value somewhere in your scope.
  });
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  browser.get("http://www.website2.com);

  var tempElement = $("inputID"); 
  tempElement.sendKeys(RefferenceTocontentOfSpan)
```